# thread is dead priority cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

I'm developing an application using some multithreading.

I have a thread that produces some data each 200ms (vibration data from an acquisition device). And each time i reacieve the data I start several tasks to do stuff. On my development PC there is no error. But when I deploy the project on a less powerful tablet I have the following message appearing several times :

> thread is dead. priority cannot be accessed.

Here is my code :

```
private void myCallback1Axis(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            try
            {
                if (runningTask == ar.AsyncState)
                {
                    data = reader.EndReadWaveform(ar); // GET THE DATA

                    // LAUNCH FFTs' THREADS
                    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
                    task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: Cancelling", task1.Id);
                                return;
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: {1}/2 In progress", task1.Id, 1);
                            ConsumeToFFT(new FFT_Parameters(data.GetRawData(), overlap1, (int)Fmax1,
                                NbLines1, HP, avg1, window1, switchFreqUnit1.Value, swVelo.Value));
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException)
                        {
                            // Any clean up code goes here.
                            Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: Cancelling", task1.Id);
                            //throw; // To ensure that the calling code knows the task was cancelled.
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            // Clean up other stuff
                            //throw; // If the calling code also needs to know.
                        }

                    }, ct);
            }
            catch (DaqException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                runningTask = null;
                myTask.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

I read that I have to :

> Put threads into background before starting ([here](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/644))

But nothing more. I'm stuck with those messages and I can not trace them. Any ideas how can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

(I'm using c#, visual studio, .net 4.0)

Comment: Where in your code do you use the `Thread.Priority` property. You need to show the code between what you have here and that call.

Comment: Also, in your linked bug report, if you scroll down to the bottom you will see the error had nothing to do with threads, it was because the program could not acccess the `libuv` library.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Thank you for the response. I do not use any `Thread.Priority` in my code.

Comment: Use `ex.ToString()` to get full information about exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not able to trace the error, and by a certain miracle it's not there any more. The only thing that I've changed is here :

```
BlockingCollection<double[]> flowData = new BlockingCollection<double[]>(1);
```

Declaring my data as BlockingCollection and then use it like that in my consumer :

```
double[] dataToProcess = flowData.Take();
```

and like that in my producer :

```
flowData.TryAdd(data.GetRawData());
```

I think that the fact that my data was not protected against thread race condition generated the error. Even if I am not using any Thread Priority in my code, having better protection of my shared data was the solution to get rid of my error.

Sorry guys, it's not the greatest explanation but at least I don't have the error anymore. Thank you for your help.